# converting JSON python time to regular time

Tags: python

I have the following python time value in JSON format...any inputs on how to convert it to to regular time format

```
u'lastUpdated': 1358294533
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[datetime.fromtimestamp](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp) from the datetime module should do it.

For example:

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> d = datetime.fromtimestamp(1358294533)
>>> d.isoformat()
'2013-01-15T19:02:13'
```

For getting a more controlled string representation of the datetime use the [datetime.strftime](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strftime) function.

Comment: @user2639990 Yes (hence the answer). Without more details we might have different definitions of what 'regular time format' means. I think it means getting a `datetime` object.

Comment: @user2639990 You can put it in [whatever format you like](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior).